Question closed without a valid reason
This question was closed by one of the moderators as offtopic although it isn't offtopic. Reason mentioned in the comment does not make sense because a summary with the question is always good to understand the concept or what exactly someone is looking for.
Research article about impact of BGP hijacking on bitcoin p2p network
There are lot of questions on bitcoin stackexchange that requested for research articles or papers: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=research

What question is "this question"?

Sorry forgot to add the link. Added.

It was pointed out to the asker that the scope of the question was unclear via a comment per a custom close reason. The question was reopened after the asker addressed some of the feedback.
